# Make ruby raise an error on duplicate key definition in hash

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to make ruby raise an error on a duplicate key definition in a hash. E.g.

```
{a: 1, b: 2, a: 3}
```

Currently this just gives a warning like so:

```
warning: key :a is duplicated and overwritten on line 1
```

I would rather get an exception

BTW: I'm on ruby 2.7

Comment: You could use RuboCop which has [Lint/DuplicateHashKey](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_lint.html#lintduplicatehashkey)

Answer (score 1):

This is a parse timew warning.
I don't think you can generate an exception:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/parse.y#L12201

Comment: Yeah, that was what I expected too and why I wondered if anyone could think of a way to have a more agressive flagging in such case rather than "just" a warning...

Comment: Since it is parse time, it does not really make sense to raise, IMHO. That would only happen for Hash literals in your code.

It is more likely to override a value at runtime, i guess.

Comment: As suggested above, you could use a static code analyser, and make this check part of your integration pipeline. In other words: If rubocop fails, then the commit does not get a green tick.